# How to have OpenJPA recursively remove children and their children?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, openjpa

My client wants me to change their application -which uses JPA- in such a way that the current Hibernate provider is replaced by OpenJPA provider. I have no OpenJPA experience and I was hoping to just have to do some configuration to achieve this goal. I removed the Hibernate provider and properties from persistence.xml and added some OpenJPA properties. I set OpenJPA as a default provider on the server (WebSphere Application Server 8.0).

When the application starts, it tries to remove children B from parent A. 
B itself has children C which should be removed from B, and children D should be removed from C. They are all configured by annotation, bi-directional: @OneToMany and @ManyToOne combinations are used for each parent/child relationship. The parent sides all have the properties mappedBy="[parent class name lowercase]", cascade=CascadeType.ALL.

Having Hibernate implemented, this worked perfectly by iterating through all elements B, explicitly deleting them by using entityManager.delete and finally emptying the collection of B's. All the C's and D's were removed as well.

Having OpenJPA implemented this results in a FK constraint violation: it looks like it is trying to remove B before the C's and D's are removed.

I tried adding orphanRemoval=true to all the @OneToMany annotations. In that case just emptying the collection of B's without explicitly removing them first. Same problem.

I looked into many articles and StackOverflow topics but I can't seem to find a solution. Can anyone help me with this please?

(Currently I have no access to the code, therefore describing it.)

Comment: http://swexplorations.blogspot.fr/2014/08/openjpa-issues-part-2.html

Comment: This confirmed suspicion and helped me to stop wanting a elegant solution. I created a generic mechanism that recurses bottom-up, removing child elements from their parents in the order by D, C, B, A. Thank you.

Comment: That's good :), good luck for you.